# LibGdx not getting files from within a directory

Tags: java, file, libgdx, directory

In my assets folder, I have a directory called "maps" which contains a list of images I want to load.

When running:

```
Gdx.files.internal("maps").exists();
```

This returns true

and:

```
Gdx.files.internal("maps/Africa.png").exists();
```

also returns true

However, trying to list these files seems to be unfeasible:

```
Gdx.files.internal("maps").list().length;
```

returns a value of 0 for the number of files in that directory

Moreover:

```
Gdx.files.internal("maps").isDirectory();
```

returns false.

This is very puzzling for what could have seemed to been a very straightforward way of getting files from a directory.

Does anyone have any ideas to circumvent this?

Comment: are you using on desktop?

Comment: yes i should have mentioned that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since desktop builds cannot use the `list()` method on internal directories, I created this script to write the file names to a text file. It uses Apache commons.io (you can put `compile "commons-io:commons-io:2.4+"` into your build.gradle to include it in your desktop module):

```
//directories within assets that you want a catalog of
static final String[] directories = {
        "completeMaps",
        "typeAMaps",
        "typeBMaps",
        "sfx",
        "music"
};

public static void main (String[] args){
    String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    for (String dir : directories){
        File directory = new File(workingDir + "/" + dir);
        File outputFile = new File(directory, "catalog.txt");
        FileUtils.deleteQuietly(outputFile); //delete previous catalog
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                FileUtils.write(outputFile, files[i].getName() + (i == files.length - 1 ? "" : "\n"), true);
            }
        } catch (IOException e){
            Util.logError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then to get a file list in a directory:

```
private FileHandle[] readDirectoryCatalogue (String directory){
    String[] fileNames = Gdx.files.internal(directory + "/catalog.txt").readString().split("\n");
    FileHandle[] files = new FileHandle[fileNames.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
        files[i] = Gdx.files.internal(directory + "/" + fileNames[i].replaceAll("\\s+",""));
    }
    return files;
}
```